# how to do something at the end of a finger drag in libgdx/android?

Tags: java, c#, android, c, libgdx

so pretty much i made a game that if you miss the target on screen the game is over, it works on my computer because it is a single click in a location but doesn't register on android because i feel like my finger is dragging by accident. i want the game to be over at the end of the drag in libgdx and am not sure how to go about it.

```
    @Override
   public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer)
    {
        game.state = (GameState.GAMEOVER);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: why is this tagged `[c#]`?

Comment: Or, for that matter, [c].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                // This is what happens on the click down... 
            } else if(arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // this is what happens on the click release
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }});
```

This would process the click if any of their motion is on the object and is based on release to vague first-engagement will be refined to further accuracy where they choose to remove their finger.

Comment: where do i put this? in my input handler because on touch is no libgdx method

Answer (score 0):

You just can't, because on android the touch drag method is called almost everytime, because your finger is still moving a little bit.. with the mouse you can keep it in the same place without problem..

But why you game should stop when the touch dragg is called?
To see if you miss your target on screen use a collision detection..